# Find method name which opened new window (c# wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, window

I'm trying to find a way to get the string name of the method call which pops up a new window. I have three button click event handlers which will open the new window but I need to know which called the .Show();

```
    private void buttonSettingsPortfolio1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settingsWindow = new MobilityPortfolioSettings();
        settingsWindow.Show();
    }

    private void buttonSettingsPortfolio2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settingsWindow = new MobilityPortfolioSettings();
        settingsWindow.Show();
    }

    private void buttonSettingsPortfolio3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settingsWindow = new MobilityPortfolioSettings();
        settingsWindow.Show();
    }
```

I don't want to have to have three separate windows! is there an opening event handler parameter which I can fetch the caller from?

Comment: If the code is identical on 3 buttons why do you keep all 3 of them and not only 1?

Comment: i need to know whichj grid location the button was clicked from. the window will run differently depending on the specific button

Comment: @MarkCorrigan You can get the grid which triggered the event easily, it is in the sender parameter of the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can simply add a public variable at MobilityPortfolioSettings class and set its value in each method, ex: in buttonSettingsPortfolio1_Click add MobilityPortfolioSettings.Variable = 1 and so on.

Comment: Ah ok yeh I was thinking of that but I then perform all of the logic in my view model but I suppose I can just supply the constructor of the vm with that public field. Seems obvious now, thanks for the push1

Answer (score 0):

Here 
`Console.write(triggeredBy);` you can output the value by logging to file or some other way . This value will indicate which path your code took.

```
private void buttonSettingsPortfolio1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Open("buttonSettingsPortfolio1_Click");
    }

    private void buttonSettingsPortfolio2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Open("buttonSettingsPortfolio2_Click");
    }

    private void buttonSettingsPortfolio3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Open("buttonSettingsPortfolio3_Click");
    }

    private Open(string triggeredBy){
        Console.write(triggeredBy); // You can write to file or output in some different way here.
        var settingsWindow = new MobilityPortfolioSettings();
        settingsWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: so i need to use the pressed button as an integer in the opened window

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Cast sender as button and then get it's name.
2. Change the MobilityPortfolioSettings constructor so that it needs a string parameter.
3. Pass the button name to the constructor.

   ```
   private void buttonSettingsPortfolio1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       string buttonName = "";
       if (sender is Button)
           buttonName = ((Button)sender).Name;

       Window settingsWindow = new MobilityPortfolioSettings(buttonName);
       settingsWindow.Show();
   }
   ```

BTW use Window as variable type instead of var.

Cheers